# SQL generate foreign key id from foreign tables varchar?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I am making a JAVA EE application, and in production I have to drop and generate a DB a lot of times.
And due to autoincrements nature, I cannot simply set the foreign key to another tables primary key after I repopulate the tables.

EXAMPLE:

```
INSERT INTO `krak`.`person` (`email`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `idaddress`) VALUES 
('jonas@example.com', 'Jonas', 'Sørensen');

INSERT INTO `krak`.`phone` (`description`, `number`, `idperson`) VALUES 
('Noka 3210', '203948129', '1');
```

When deleting and creating the person in krak schema his primary key will not be 1 when he is created the second time it will be 2 due to autoincrement.

Is there a way which i can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO `krak`.`phone` (`description`, `number`, `idperson`) VALUES 
('Noka 3210', '203948129', 'WHERE 'krak'.'person' email = hisEmail');
```

I know this is a silly example, but I hope it shows you what I trying to do :)

Comment: You're looking for last_insert_id()

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the questions correctly, I think your question is about krak.phone table. You want to drop and recreate krak.phone table multiple times. If that's right, then I would suggest that you use a stored procedure to insert into krak.phone based on krak.person.

For example,

```
INSERT INTO  `krak`.`phone` (`description`, `number`, `idperson`) 
SELECT 'Noka 3210', '203948129', ID FROM krak.person P WHERE P.email = hisEmail;
```